# C# and mysql repetitive queries

Tags: c#, mysql

I am looking for opinions and also if I missed an option.

I am writing a small inventory and sales tracking system using C# and mysql (MySqlDataReader).  Since mysql does not allow multiple result sets (MySqlDataReaders) per connection, I have a dilemma.  The lines of the sale form are a user control.  One of the fields to select is the item number.  Since I don't know how many items I will have or how many lines will end up on a sales order, I'm not sure which way to code this.  Here are the options that I have come up with.

1) Execute the SQL multiple times (one per user control) to fetch the items.

2) Open multiple connections so I can have multiple result sets.

3) Dump all of the items to a List in the MainForm and retrieve it in each user control.

Option 3 seems like the best option from a reduce "hitting the database standpoint" but if I have thousands of items, will that cause me memory issues?

Does anyone have an idea which would be the most efficient (taking database and memory into account) or are there other options that I have not thought of?

Comment: rule of thumb: always try to let DB do the dirty work. If you can ask the DB to constrain your result set instead of doing that in your code (in memory) then do that. If you can reduce the number of round trip, do that. if you can get all the result you need in one statement instead of going to the DB multiple times, do that

Comment: Exactly what is the "item number" users are selecting? Don't you need to query the database to show them valid choices, or are you having them "guess"? _Also, an option 4 would be to build a single query based from the items, using something like an IN condition....it complicates make a parameterized query, but is not uncommon._

Comment: This is way too broad. A great deal more information is needed for a worthwhile answer

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on that.  The item number is a combobox listing all of the available items for them to select from.

Comment: To further clarify the dilemma, currently each time I add a line (user control) to the form, I need to get all of the items to add to the combobox and since i am adding the lines to the form based on a query retrieving the existing lines on the order (in the case of updates), I can't execute the query for the item number combobox because I already have an open result set (sale order lines).  That is where my thought of a second connection came it.

Comment: If all the comboboxes use the same list of items (from the database), you should be caching the results of the query that gives you the list in an appropriate collection (and not using the result set directly, nor leaving the result open).

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to solve this in ASP.Net Webforms.

1. A single databound control, like a GridView or ListView
2. A Repeater control

In either case, pushing 1000s of records to a web page is never a good idea. If you have that many results to a query, you want to get more creative about how you show that to the user.